# PlatfotmIO, How to have a windowed terminal?

Tags: arduino, platformio

How to have a windowed terminal in platformIO?

I'm trying to set the serial monitor in an another screen on my computer

Thanks for help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i think this [site](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/vs-code-platformio-ide-esp32-esp8266-arduino/) is going to help you to set up everything. Plus to open the terminal in vs code you could use Ctrl + ` to see your terminal windowed.